# Speed remaining at 0 when moving

Tags: android, location

I am currently trying to get a user's current speed in my application.

I've managed to connect to the GooglePlay Services, and it is apparently updating, though I think it is calculating the speed improperly, because even when moving the application displays that the speed of the person is zero.

**What is wrong with my current code, and how can I fix it?**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    float Distance = OldLocation.distanceTo(location);
    long TimeDiff = location.getTime()-OldLocation.getTime();
    long SecondDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeDiff);
    float Speed = Distance/SecondDiff;

    OldLocation = location;
}
```

I initialise global variable `OldLocation` in `onConnected()`;

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    }
}
```

Whats the exact issue? Is the application simply not getting the Location properly? Or is it because the global variable `OldLocation` not being set properly? Or is something else entirely?

Comment: cast `SecondDiff` to float before dividing, would probably help

Comment: can someone please tell me why this is a duplicate?